# helm-git-grep and helm-swoop at the same time

Tags: helm

I heavily rely on `helm-git-grep` to find stuff.
When there are just too many results though, I'd like to narrow the results down with file name. (possibly with helm-swoop)

Here's what I do for the above situation.

1. I run `helm-git-grep` then,
   save it to wgrep buffer using `helm-get-grep-run-save-buffer`,
   isearch or helm-swoop on this buffer to narrow down.
2. `helm-git-grep` and find too many results.
   quit `helm-git-grep` and run `helm-browse-project` to filter on files first,
   then run `helm-ls-git-run-grep` on filtered files to narrow down.

I feel these two options are subpar and wonder if there's a better way.

If I do `helm-git-grep` then try to run `helm-swoop` I get `helm: Error: Trying to run helm within a running helm session` error.